# What is the point of extra T pipe under my vanity?

Tags: pipe, bathroom-fixtures, vanity

I noticed there is an extra T pipe under my vanity for cold water. It goes to basement and it looks like there is a hole in it as well. I cannot understand what does it do? It looks like there is constant water that goes inside it (I can see it from the small hole it has).

[image]

The strange T part in close look:
[image]

Comment: Looks more like some type of valve than a plain t-joint.  Something to regulate pressure(?).

Comment: You can actually _see_ water through that little gap in the nut? Can you stick a small screwdriver in there and pull it out wet? Is there water there _all_ the time or just when using the sink?

Comment: @FreeMan there is water all the time, I noticed that it is causing minor leak recently. Maybe it is damaged and there should be water only sometimes?

Comment: Does the pipe going to the basement go to something like a floor drain that would usually not have water flowing to it (if not for the water that this source provides)?

Comment: Trap filler is indeed a good bet, @GregHill

Comment: I searched about trap filter and I think that is it. I followed the line in basement and it goes to drain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a [trap primer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_primer). It allows just a little bit of water to be bypassed from the usual horizontal path (headed to your sink) and sends it out the vertical pipe, where it ends up keeping a trap (often in a floor drain) from drying out and allowing sewer gas into your house.

Here's a photo of one from a vendor. https://www.sustainablesupply.com/products/zurn-trap-primer-bronze-pipe-dia-1-2-in-z1022-xl-1-2-ip-c1912466

[image: trap primer]

And another one (from https://www.wilmar.com/Sku/15-1843/mifab-continuous-flow-trap-seal-primer-with-12-in-connections-779897963421-mi-tsp-1) that looks even more like the one in your photo:

[image: trap primer]

(Thanks to Greg Hill and Ecnerwal for pointing me in the right direction with their comments.)